# How Expand the table view cells?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I want to know that how the row size will increase and expanded when click on one row..
Please give me some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If it goes for all rows:
Use a variable cellSize for creating every cell, and when the table gets initially created, use that cellSize. 
In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, increase the value of that cellSize and do a [tableview reloaddata]. That should do the trick...

If it goes for one row, you should check when creating the rows if the value in the array (the array you want to view in the table) is the correct value, and if so, increase the cellSize, if not, use the original cellSize. Not sure if this last part works, but I can't really think of anything why it wouldn't. Try it out and let me know!